# Project Centennial integrate Cortana Error DEP0700

Tags: cortana, windows-10-desktop, desktop-bridge

I am trying to create a Desktop Bridge app and would like to integrate Cortana voice commands with it. My Package.appxmanifest of Bridge app is as follows:

```
    <Dependencies>    
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.14393.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.14393.0" />
    <PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop" MinVersion="12.0.40652.5" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="MyBridgeApp\SampleBridgeApp.exe" EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication">
      <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="Sample Bridge App" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png" Description="Sample Bridge App" BackgroundColor="transparent">
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png">
        </uap:DefaultTile>
      </uap:VisualElements>
      <Extensions>
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.appService" EntryPoint="SampleAppService.BackgroundTask">
          <uap:AppService Name="app.bridge.sample" />
        </uap:Extension>
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.personalAssistantLaunch" />            
      </Extensions>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="microphone" />
  </Capabilities>
```

The problems are:

1. If I go with the approach of using Cortana voice commands in a foreground app, I think it's not possible as my app's EntryPoint does not point to an App class, instead it points to my bridge app i.e.

   > Executable="MyBridgeApp\SampleBridgeApp.exe" EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication"

   2. If I go with launching a background process in my app when Cortana voice command is activated, both Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 are giving the following error due to my Package.appxmanifest:-

> Error     DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073CF6] AppxManifest.xml(39,10): error 0x80070032: Cannot register the (SampleBridgeApp'sId) package because the following error was encountered while registering the windows.personalAssistantLaunch extension: The request is not supported.
>   .  Try again and contact the package publisher if the problem persists.

Can anyone suggest me if there is any workaround to this problem or is it not possible to use Cortana with a desktop bridge app at all?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the [UWP APIs available to a packaged desktop app (Desktop Bridge)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-supported-api) document. The cortana relevant APIs do not support in desktop bridge app.

The error message `registering the windows.personalAssistantLaunch extension: The request is not supported` also has explained it.